# Query an endpoint in order to set the scenario URL path?

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a scenario which simply does this:

```
val scn = scenario("Event Scenario")
    .exec(
        http("pwn_event").get("/events/%d", eventId)
    )

setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(1000) during(1 minute))
    .protocols(httpConf)
```

Basically, obliterate `/events/%d` with 1000 requests per second for one minute.

The problem is that I need to make some kind of query to get `eventId`.

Is there an easy way that at the beginning of the simulation, I could query an endpoint, get the `eventId` from the JSON result, and then start the actual simulation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Gatling DSL for this, but you can use a before {} block where you can use whatever code to perform initialization tasks, such as using AsyncHttpClient.